# How do i convert a JS object to JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I convert a JS object to a JSON string?

```
var o = { name: "a", id:5};
var sz = //???
alert('The json will look like ' + sz);
```

I would like to do it natively if possible, or using jQuery if not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS object to JSON string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834030/js-object-to-json-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for the `JSON.stringify` method:

```
var sz = JSON.stringify(o);
```

This method is part of the ECMAScript 5 Standard, and almost every browser includes it.

For older browsers and IE < 8, you can include the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) file.